# How can I resolve the error: TypeError: invalid Figure property: Layout Layout Bad property path: Layout ^^^^^^

Tags: python, plotly

Hello I am working through a Python Crash Course book and one of the tasks is to build a simple map of earthquake locations using plotly. The goal is to have the program open an HTML on my Safari browser that displays a map of where the earthquakes have taken place. However, when I try to run the code I receive the error:

TypeError: invalid Figure property: Layout
Layout
Bad property path:
Layout
^^^^^^

No HTML or pop up occurs in the browser.

The code I am running:

```
 `import json

from plotly.graph_objs import Scattergeo, Layout
from plotly import offline

#explore the sturcture of the data
filename = 'eq_data_1_day_m1.json'
with open(filename) as f:
    all_eq_data = json.load(f)

readable_file = 'new_readable_eq_data.json'
with open(readable_file, 'w') as f:
    json.dump(all_eq_data, f, indent=4)

all_eq_dicts = all_eq_data['features']
print(len(all_eq_dicts))

mags, lons, lats = [], [], []
for eq_dict in all_eq_dicts:
    mag = eq_dict['properties']['mag']
    lon = eq_dict['geometry']['coordinates'][0]
    lat = eq_dict['geometry']['coordinates'][1]
    mags.append(mag)
    lons.append(lon)
    lats.append(lat)

#map the earthquakes
data = [Scattergeo(lon=lons, lat=lats)]
my_layout = Layout(title='Global Earthquakes')

fig = {'data': data, 'Layout': my_layout}
offline.plot(fig, filename='global_earthquakes.html')

`
```

I have tried to rewrite the code and copy it over and over again from the book but it won't run. Plotly is up to date. I have been able to extract data from the 'new_readable_eq_data.json' file so I do not think that is the problem. The error is specifically found on the last line of code:

offline.plot(fig, filename='global_earthquakes.html')

What are some ways to get around this problem?
Thanks.

Comment: Which line do you get the error on?

Comment: I get the error on the offline.plot(fig, filename='global_earthquakes.html')

Comment: It seems that the use of that function is no longer recommended, according to https://plotly.com/python/renderers/. From what I can see it looks like the function was replaced with 'the renderers framework'

Comment: If my below answer helped I would much appreciate you marking it as a correct answer

Comment: Thanks for the help. It's saying AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'write_html' and it says the same thing with the to_html.

Comment: I see, yeah this is due to the fact that dig is a dictionary object. I assume there is a constructor of some sort in v4

Comment: You've been very helpful. Thank you! Went down a rabbit hole exploring all the cool mapping capabilities through plotly.

Comment: No worries. Me too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that with the release of v4 the offline features have been replaced by 'the renderers framework'. You can find information on this here: https://plotly.com/python/v4-migration/#offline-features-plotlyoffline-replaced-by-renderers-framework--html-export

> In version 3, the plotly.offline.plot function was used to export figures to HTML files. In version 4, this function has been reimplemented on top of the new to_html and write_html functions from the plotly.io module. These functions have a slightly more consistent API (see docstrings for details), and going forward we recommend using them directly when performing HTML export. When working with a graph object figure, these functions are also available as the .to_html and .write_html figure methods.

You should be able to use:

```
fig.write_html("global_earthquakes.html")
```

Edit:

To construct the fig, you need to use the following. (I found it [here](https://plotly.com/python/map-configuration/))

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(go.Scattergeo())
fig.update_layout(height=300, margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0})
```

In terms of plotting points onto the map, i've found this [here](https://plotly.com/python/scatter-plots-on-maps/):

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.gapminder().query("year == 2007")
fig = px.scatter_geo(df, locations="iso_alpha",
                     size="pop", # size of markers, "pop" is one of the columns of gapminder
                     )
fig.show()
```